# How do I bring the Floating Action Button outside the app in IOS and make it run as visible, moveable and clickable?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background, floating-action-button

I need a creating floating widgets/overlays that can be shown while the app is in the background. like below

[image]

The floating widget/overlay must only show when the app is in the background. When a user clicks on it, the app must open.

I want this in Xamarin Forms and I prefer to implement this is in platform-specific code.

I can achieve this in android using the below link but I am getting difficult to get this in ios.

https://github.com/JustinScott/AppFloater
https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote
https://github.com/sezeryesiltas/chat-head-demo
https://github.com/callmekarthik/FBChatHeadExample

Please help me to find this in **iOS**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do this in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, But unfortunately iOS doesn't support such kind of development. You can add the Floating button inside the app but you can't add that over other apps. Apple also not suggest doing that.

For reference:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/78360